# Как создать класс помеченный @Service с областью видимости scope=session в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

Есть класс

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/routesOnMap")
public class RoutesOnMapController {

    @Autowired
    RoutesOnMapService service;
...
}
```

В нем инъектится свойство RoutesOnMapService service.

```
@Service
public class RoutesOnMapService {

    @Autowired
    RoutesOnMapDao dao;

    @Autowired
    RouteDictionaryDao routeDictionaryDao;
...
}
```

Нужно чтобы объект класса RoutesOnMapService создавался каждый раз новый для каждой новой сессии. Потому что происходимые внутри вычисления нужно изолировать от таких же вычислений другого пользователя (который в этот момент решил использовать тот же функционал приложения)?

---

@Roman
Сделал вот так

`@Service
public class RoutesOnMapService {

```
@Autowired
RoutesOnMapDao dao;

@Autowired
RouteDictionaryDao routeDictionaryDao;
```

...
}`

ПОлучил

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routesOnMapService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Что за беда? Помогите

Comment: А просто навесить `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)` на `RoutesOnMapService` не помогает?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, добавил вот такую строчку.

```
@Scope(value = "session",  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

над RoutesOnMapService классом.

В web.xml у меня теперь два listener

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Теперь работает